# iOS special characters in url

Tags: objective-c, ios7, restkit, afnetworking

I try to make an api call:

```
api.app.com/foo/search/Öhm
```

where Öhm is the search term. The problem is that this url causes a bad url exception, while normal chars work well. I tried with

```
[searchText stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

However this produces a lot of % signs. The api expects Öhm. Any solution for this problem? I am using restkit.

The full error:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x16e719d0
>   {NSUnderlyingError=0x16d70d10 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad
>   URL} 2014-04-03 18:26:55.404 My App[6844:3807] E
>   restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:243 GET '(null)' (0 / 0
>   objects) [request=0.0084s mapping=0.0000s total=0.0769s]: Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x16e719d0
>   {NSUnderlyingError=0x16d70d10 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad
>   URL}

The termin is (null) instead of Öhm.

Code:

```
[[ApiSearchManager sharedManager] search:^(NSArray *result){
    //handle success
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //handle fail - it fails for Öhm
} query:searchTerm];
```

and on the lower level:

```
- (void) search:(void (^)(NSArray *))success failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *, NSError *))failure query:(NSString *)query{

    [self getObjectsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"foo/search/%@", query] parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        if (success) {
            success(mappingResult.array);
        }
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if (failure) {
            failure(operation, error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code that causes the "bad url exception"?

Comment: I ran `NSString* s = @"http://api.app.com/foo/search/Öhm"; NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:s];` and I didn't get any exception.

Comment: @matt it's inside restkit, and restkit uses asihttprequest internally.

Comment: You still didn't show your code.

Comment: @matt I edited my question with the code

Comment: What version of RestKit are you using? RestKit uses AFNetworking internally, not ASIHTTPRequest (not sure if it ever did...). And show a full stack trace for the exception.

Comment: @Wain sorry I should have been more precise. There is no exception, when ÖÄÜ are passed to the query, the failure callback will be triggered for those chars with a log message that I posted in my question. I am using the latest restkit, I think 0.23

Comment: I guess you mean 0.20.3 which is a bit old now, the current version would be 0.22 I think

Comment: @Wain correct I mean 0.20.3

Comment: It might be worth upgrading as I couldn't put a finger on exactly what's wrong currently...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The % signs are *escaping*, and that *is* how the URL should be transmitted. At the server side, the URL gets interpreted (unescaped) and the server-side code will see the special characters as you intended. For example it's very common to see URL's with %20 in them. ASCII character 20 (hex) is a space, so server-side code that obtains the URL (appropriately decoded) see a space in there.

Comment: I would agree, but he says the API expects the UTF8 characters. And as you know, the rules on URLs have changed so that UTF8 is now legal.

Comment: @RobP The percent signs are *escaped* characters (while all characters are *encoded*).

Comment: URLs support UTF-8 - if you translate the UTF-8 to and from ASCII according to RFC 3490. Which means they don't support UTF-8.

Comment: @Nikolai right you are, nomenclature is improved now.

Comment: @matt do you have some reference on how URL rules have changed?

Answer (score 1):

This section of the log:

```
GET '(null)' (0 / 0 objects) [request=0.0084s mapping=0.0000s total=0.0769s]:
```

Means you're doing a `GET`, that the request URL is `nil` (which would be bad), so status code was obtained because no request was actually sent, it took a little time, blah blah

So, The URL loading system couldn't create a valid URL with which to make your request.

I'm going to guess that the only way you can achieve this is to not have a properly configured `baseURL` in your `RKObjectManager`. Check that. *(though I would expect that to fail earlier - so you may be reduced to debugging around `RKObjectRequestOperation.m`, line 243, and back up the call stack)*